# List group en boostrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy intentando usar las **list group** de *boostrap*. Pero no consigo que funcione, No me cambia el contenido al pulsar en la lista. Os dejo el siguiente ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer. El objetivo es pulsar una de los siguientes items de la lista **home, profile, messages y settings** y que al lado me ponga información para cada uno. Si no entendido mal el uso de esta lista es simplemente importanto el **bootstrap.min.js** y añadiendo clases e id correctos, funciona sin la necesidad de hacer tu el **js**.

[image: ejemplo]

Tengo importado lo siguiente de bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

El codigo:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-4">

    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home"

        role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile"

        role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages"

        role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings"

        role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-8">

    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">

        Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat

        tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit

        occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat

        aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in

        cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">

        Cupidatat quis ad sint excepteur laborum in esse qui. Et excepteur consectetur ex nisi eu do cillum ad

        laborum. Mollit et eu officia dolore sunt Lorem culpa qui commodo velit ex amet id ex. Officia anim

        incididunt laboris deserunt anim aute dolor incididunt veniam aute dolore do exercitation. Dolor nisi

        culpa ex ad irure in elit eu dolore. Ad laboris ipsum reprehenderit irure non commodo enim culpa

        commodo veniam incididunt veniam ad.

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">

        Ut ut do pariatur aliquip aliqua aliquip exercitation do nostrud commodo reprehenderit aute ipsum

        voluptate. Irure Lorem et laboris nostrud amet cupidatat cupidatat anim do ut velit mollit consequat

        enim tempor. Consectetur est minim nostrud nostrud consectetur irure labore voluptate irure. Ipsum id

        Lorem sit sint voluptate est pariatur eu ad cupidatat et deserunt culpa sit eiusmod deserunt.

        Consectetur et fugiat anim do eiusmod aliquip nulla laborum elit adipisicing pariatur cillum.

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">

        Irure enim occaecat labore sit qui aliquip reprehenderit amet velit. Deserunt ullamco ex elit nostrud

        ut dolore nisi officia magna sit occaecat laboris sunt dolor. Nisi eu minim cillum occaecat aute est

        cupidatat aliqua labore aute occaecat ea aliquip sunt amet. Aute mollit dolor ut exercitation irure

        commodo non amet consectetur quis amet culpa. Quis ullamco nisi amet qui aute irure eu. Magna labore

        dolor quis ex labore id nostrud deserunt dolor eiusmod eu pariatur culpa mollit in irure.

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Verificaste si las rutas donde tienes alojados los archivos CSS y JS son las correctas?

A simple vista parece ser que solo copiaste y pegaste estas lineas:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Haz una prueba reemplazándolas por estas:

Para el CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Los componentes de Boostrap requieren el uso de JavaScript para funcionar. Específicamente, requieren jQuery, Popper.js y sus propios complementos de JavaScript.

Para el JS:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-4">

    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home"

        role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile"

        role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages"

        role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>

      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings"

        role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-8">

    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">

        Velit aute mollit ipsum ad dolor consectetur nulla officia culpa adipisicing exercitation fugiat

        tempor. Voluptate deserunt sit sunt nisi aliqua fugiat proident ea ut. Mollit voluptate reprehenderit

        occaecat nisi ad non minim tempor sunt voluptate consectetur exercitation id ut nulla. Ea et fugiat

        aliquip nostrud sunt incididunt consectetur culpa aliquip eiusmod dolor. Anim ad Lorem aliqua in

        cupidatat nisi enim eu nostrud do aliquip veniam minim.

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">

        Cupidatat quis ad sint excepteur laborum in esse qui. Et excepteur consectetur ex nisi eu do cillum ad

        laborum. Mollit et eu officia dolore sunt Lorem culpa qui commodo velit ex amet id ex. Officia anim

        incididunt laboris deserunt anim aute dolor incididunt veniam aute dolore do exercitation. Dolor nisi

        culpa ex ad irure in elit eu dolore. Ad laboris ipsum reprehenderit irure non commodo enim culpa

        commodo veniam incididunt veniam ad.

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">

        Ut ut do pariatur aliquip aliqua aliquip exercitation do nostrud commodo reprehenderit aute ipsum

        voluptate. Irure Lorem et laboris nostrud amet cupidatat cupidatat anim do ut velit mollit consequat

        enim tempor. Consectetur est minim nostrud nostrud consectetur irure labore voluptate irure. Ipsum id

        Lorem sit sint voluptate est pariatur eu ad cupidatat et deserunt culpa sit eiusmod deserunt.

        Consectetur et fugiat anim do eiusmod aliquip nulla laborum elit adipisicing pariatur cillum.

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">

        Irure enim occaecat labore sit qui aliquip reprehenderit amet velit. Deserunt ullamco ex elit nostrud

        ut dolore nisi officia magna sit occaecat laboris sunt dolor. Nisi eu minim cillum occaecat aute est

        cupidatat aliqua labore aute occaecat ea aliquip sunt amet. Aute mollit dolor ut exercitation irure

        commodo non amet consectetur quis amet culpa. Quis ullamco nisi amet qui aute irure eu. Magna labore

        dolor quis ex labore id nostrud deserunt dolor eiusmod eu pariatur culpa mollit in irure.

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Prueba y nos comentas.

Comment: Siento que toda esta respuesta pudo caber perfectamente en un comentario, no estás asegurando que el error sea ese, sólo preguntando (en una respuesta) si el OP se fijó o no en añadir correctamente las librerías.

Comment: Buenas tenias razón, solo hay algo que no entiendo si importo las librerías remotamente funciona. Yo las tenia descargadas y no funcionaban. Tenía todas importadas eso sí. Una duda que tengo es ¿Que es mejor tenerlas descargadas o importarlas remotament?

Comment: @JheymanMejia el comentario me limita, por eso lo hice como respuesta, porque sabia cual era el error y que mi respuesta iba a estar acertada, tal como sucedió.

Comment: @Caldeiro Si te sirvió la respuesta el mejor agradecimiento que puedes dar es darle un positivo y marcarla como aceptada. Y respondiendo a tu comentario, es mejor descargarlas y así aseguras que todo lo tienes tu, porque si las importas remotamente dependes de terceros que pueden mover los archivos y cambian las URL's.

Comment: @JoseDarioCorrea no sabías, no hay forma de saber si una ruta existe o no si nunca se muestra. Que hayas acertado, es otra cosa...